# FFI with dependencies in Racket?

Tags: raspberry-pi, racket, ffi, wiringpi

I developed a very simple FFI for the Wiring PI library, to be able to control a Raspberry Pi using Racket.

This worked well, but only covers the base functionality. I wanted to extend this to also use the lcd.h from the libwiringPiDev.so, so that I could create an FFI to control an LCD.

Normally, when you compile a C file that uses the LCD, you tag both the standard library and the development library when compiling:

```
-lwiringPi -lwiringPiDev
```

In my LCD FFI I did the following:

```
(define-ffi-definer define-lcd
  (ffi-lib "usr/lib/libwiringPiDev.so"))
```

However, when I try to require that racket file, I run into:

```
; ffi-lib: couldn't open "/usr/lib/libwiringPiDev.so"
;   (/usr/lib/libwiringPiDev.so: undefined symbol: digitalRead) [,bt for
;   context]
```

The digitalRead function exists in the base library but not in the dev library...how do I do a "FFI with dependencies" so that Racket can properly manage both libraries to be able to find the necessary symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading libwiringPi.so first in global mode, then load libwiringPiDev.so:

```
(define-ffi-definer define-lcd
  (ffi-lib "/usr/lib/libwiringPi.so" #:global? #t))
(define-ffi-definer define-lcd-dev
  (ffi-lib "/usr/lib/libwiringPiDev.so"))
```

The `#:global? #t` argument corresponds to setting the `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag in the call to `dlopen`, and the man page for dlopen (on my Linux system) says

> RTLD_GLOBAL
> The symbols defined by this shared object will be made available
> for symbol resolution of subsequently loaded shared objects.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Interestingly, if I require the lcd.rkt first, and then wiringpi.rkt, it works properly...but if I require wiringpi.rkt first and then lcd.rkt, I get the "undefined symbol" error...what might be causing that?

Comment: I could imagine a scenario where these dependencies become much more complicated and the ordering of requires could become much more tedious.

Comment: I think this library is atypical, and that usually shared libraries just link to the libraries that they depend on rather than expecting the symbols to be defined in the global namespace.